# Finding the possible Jordan canonical forms of a matrix, given its characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have a complex square matrix $M$ with:

Characteristic polynomial: $(\lambda-3)^4(\lambda+2)^5(\lambda-5)^2$

Minimal polynomial: $(\lambda-3)^2(\lambda+2)^3(\lambda-5)$

$\dim(E_3)=2$ and $\dim(E_{-2})=3$ where $E_\lambda$ is the eigenspace for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

Would $\dim(E_5)=1$? Is it really so simple as that the dimension of the eigen space is the multiplicity of that eigenvalue in the minimal polynomial?

However, my main reason for making this post is I would like someone to help me gain insight into the possible Jordan canonical forms of $M$. Thank you.

Would

Comment: Multiplicity in the characteristic polynomial gives you the dimensions of the generalized eigenspaces. Multiplicity in the minimal polynomial tells you the size of the largest corresponding Jordan blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\forall \lambda_i$, $m_g(\lambda_i)$ is equal to the number of Jordan blocks relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, while the powers that appear in the minimal polynomial represent the biggest Jordan block relative to a specific eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. 
The algebraic multiplicity $m_a(\lambda_i)$ is equal to the sum of the orders of the blocks relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

We have $$\chi(t)=(t-3)^4(t+2)^5(t-5)^2, \mu(t)=(t-3)^2(t+2)^3(t-5)$$
$$\text{and }m_g(3)=2,m_g(-2)=3.$$
The informations that we know are that the sum of the orders of the Jordan blocks relative to the eigenvalue $3$ is $4$ and the biggest block has dimension $2$.
The sum of the orders of the Jordan blocks relative to $-2$ is $5$ and the biggest of them has dimension $3$.
Finally, we have that the sum of Jordan blocks relative to $5$ is $2$ and the biggest of them has order $1$.
The possibilities that we have are:
$$J_3\to\begin{cases}(\textbf{J}_\textbf{3,2},J_{3,2})\\(\textbf{J}_\textbf{3,2}J_{3,1},J_{3,1})\text{ not acceptable} \end{cases}$$
$$ J_{-2}\to\begin{cases}(\textbf{J}_\textbf{-2,3},J_{-2,2})\text{ not acceptable}\\(\textbf{J}_\textbf{-2,3},J_{-2,1},J_{-2,1}) \end{cases}$$
$$J_5\to (J_{5,1},J_{5,1})$$
In the notation "$J_{i,k}$", $i$ is the eigenvalue and $k$ is the dimension of the block.
The idea is that, after we fix the biggest block, we study the possible partitions of the number of the remaining blocks.

Comment: Thanks L!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome Eugene!